# Show Text on taskbar

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.5, taskbar

I'm working on an app that will simply be a taskbar application for showing the temperature.

But I'm having a hard time getting the `notifyIcon` to just show Text and not an Icon.

If there is a different control I have to use, please let me know.

If you need any additional information, let me know that too.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's called `NotifyIcon` for a reason.  Perhaps you could update the image manually by drawing a blank image (white, black, whatever) and drawing text on top of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but i wont take the fun out of it for you by showing you the code. I wil however tell you the steps

1)Create a bitmap image(hard coded) with the text you want to display as the icon

2)Convert the bitmap image to and icon

3)Set the icon as you icon for the notification

and that's it :D. The rest should be easy for you. Simply pass the values etc etc etc

Comment: No prob.Let me know how it goes

Comment: as long as there aren't too many 100+ degree days my app works like a charm. its tricky getting it to look good with such small spaces.